# How is Java concurrency implemented for Windows?

Tags: java, concurrency

Does anyone know how is Java concurrency implemented for Windows?  Does it call the native Windows API?  I downloaded the source code from OpenJDK.  So far, I haven't found any file related to concurrency.   Thanks.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm ?

Comment: @TheBlastOne The question is about the *implementation*, not about the API.

Comment: it has to call the native windows api eventually, and Thread.start is a native method. is the question where to find the code that calls the windows code?

Comment: [This](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp) should get you started (look for StartThread) - [Windows specific files](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/os/windows/vm/).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referring to the two thread models used throughout the history of the Java Runtime: the **green thread** model (user-level threads, managed by the JVM) and the non-green thread model (**native threads**, managed by the OS).

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713142/green-threads-vs-non-green-threads), green threads aren't used anymore (and haven't been used for a long time) on any of the popular platforms (Windows, Linux, Solaris). So, to answer your question, **Java threads are real threads** at the implementation level.

The `synchronized` keyword functions based on the fact that every object is associated with a "hidden" monitor. Therefore, `synchronized` works by emitting the bytecodes for `monitorenter` and `monitorexit`, which are instructions *to the JVM* to lock and unlock respectively that hidden monitor.

Comment: yes, but i need an answer to other concurrency constructs too, not just threads.

Comment: @CandyChiu I've added a small description for `synchronized`. Can you name what other constructs you're interested in?

Comment: this is not enough.  i want to know details such as whether they used kernel objects (mutex) or user mode objects (critical region).  I am digging around openjdk's source.  I will eventually come to something.  I was hoping someone has already done the digging and point me to the files.

Comment: @CandyChiu I think you should include these details to your question, so it has better chances if someone can help you about those specific aspects.