# Are web workers green or red?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

We can create a new instance of a [web worker](http://caniuse.com/webworkers) as such:

```
var worker = new Worker('task.js');
```

Are each web worker backed by its own [native thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5713185/632951), or is there a pool of native threads allocated per window which all web workers of that window will then share?

Are there standard implementation guidelines that browsers are supposed to follow?

**What about the state of popular browsers like Chrome, FireFox, etc?**

Answer (score 7):

The W3C standard says this about Web Workers execution context:

> Create a separate parallel execution environment (i.e. a separate thread or process or equivalent construct), and run the rest of these steps asynchronously in that context.

Essentially, a browser can implement this however it pleases. Any, or all, or none of your suggestions may apply.

Here's the reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/

Comment: But the wording is extremely vague: When they talk about a "separate thread", do they mean a "separate green thread" or a "separate red thread"? And "asynchronously" is of course, even worse. We could do *asynchronous* scripting via good old `setTimeout` as well..

Comment: The specification doesn't even specify that a separate thread be used, just that a separate asynchronous context be established. The distinction between green or red threads, or no separate thread at all, is a matter for the browser implementation.