# Threads : Grean Threads Vs User Threads

Tags: java

This is a sort of noob question , but can anyone expalin how "Green Threads"   and "User  Threads"  are different from each other .

```
OR
```

Are they mean the same thing ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713142/green-threads-vs-non-green-threads.

Comment: Green threads in the context of Java are a thing of the past (say +/- 15-20 years).