# JVM green threads support and operating systems native threads support

Tags: multithreading, jvm, operating-system, native

1) Is "green threads" something supported in all JVMs ? 
If not, then what is the reason that it is not supported by some of them ?

2) Do all modern general purpose operating systems support native threads ?

Comment: I think this is answered in [Green Threads vs Non Green Threads](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5713142/217324)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In general, modern VMs do not use green threads. These days Thread Pooling is more common.
2. The question is too broad. What do you mean by all operating systems? Embeded systems on a variety of chips included? Most general purpose OS running on modern processors do have native threads.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by saying thread pooling in that context? If modern JVM runs on some OS which does not support native threads, what will do the JVM if it does not support green threads ?                   2) I meant general purpose OS. I have edited my question already. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can read about thread pooling here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html. What happens on a system without native threads depends on the System and JVM implementation. Some systems without native threads have a notion of user scheduled threads, For example fibers or (yes) green threads. For more detailed explanation you should look into the appropriate system and JVM documentation.