# enforcing core list for the kernel threads in the JVM

Tags: java, linux-kernel

Is there a way to enforce the cpu list on which the kernel threads which the JVM runs when running a java application will run.
since kernel threads can run on all cores inclusing isolcpu cores I have no control on which kernel threads can run on these isolcores and I see in fact that when running java applications together with my packet processing application which runs on the isolated cores I have issues with performance, which otherwise (when java applications do not run) do not exist.

Comment: I don't understand your Question.  Java doesn't use kernel threads.  A JVM is an ordinary user-space application that uses user-space threads; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278425/are-java-threads-created-in-user-space-or-kernel-space

Answer (score 0):

You can use `taskset(1)` to set the mask of allowed CPU cores for a process, including your java process.